Deterministic AES encryption implementation without using external libraries
I want to encrypt some data in the database. I want it to be as secure as possible with one caveat - I need to search for ciphers that encode the same data, hence I need the ciphers for any given string to be deterministic.
I was looking at AES-GCM-SIV and AES-SIV for nonce misuse-resistant implementations because there was another post mentioning it, but I either found some old archived GitHub projects or big 3rd party wrappers for c libraries.
I was playing around and implemented my own version using AesGcm and Rfc2898DeriveBytes to generate nonce based on input string:
internal class AesGcmStringEncryptor(IOptions<AppOptions> options)
{
    private readonly byte[] _key = Base32.FromBase32(options.Value.AesGcmBase32Key);
    private readonly byte[] _salt = Base32.FromBase32(options.Value.AesGcmBase32Salt);

    private const int TagSize = 16; // MaxSize = 16
    private const int NonceSize = 12; // MaxSize = 12

    public string Encrypt(string input)
    {
        // PBKDF2 pseudo random derivation function to build deterministic IVs.
        var ivGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(input, _salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);

        using var aes = new AesGcm(_key, TagSize);

        var nonceBytes = ivGenerator.GetBytes(NonceSize);

        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        var cipherBytes = new byte[inputBytes.Length];

        var tagBytes = new byte[TagSize];

        aes.Encrypt(nonceBytes, inputBytes, cipherBytes, tagBytes);

        var combinedResult = Combine(nonceBytes, cipherBytes, tagBytes);

        return Base32.ToBase32(combinedResult);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string input)
    {
        using var aes = new AesGcm(_key, TagSize);

        var combinedResult = Base32.FromBase32(input);

        var dataLength = combinedResult.Length - NonceSize - TagSize;

        var resultBytes = new byte[dataLength];

        var nonceBytes = combinedResult[..NonceSize];
        var cipherBytes = combinedResult[NonceSize..^TagSize];
        var tagBytes = combinedResult[^TagSize..];

        aes.Decrypt(nonceBytes, cipherBytes, tagBytes, resultBytes);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
    }
}

Do you guys see anything wrong with this code?

Blind index is a good shout here, thanks! I was just wondering in my implementation what would be an actual vulnerability here, because IV would be reused only for the same input value (unless there are collisions in Rfc2898DeriveBytes output).

I don't see anything overly wrong, but it makes much more sense to create an deterministic cipher using AEAD & CTR mode encryption. You definitely don't want a password based key derivation function if you already have a key, and you certainly don't want a high iteration count and including  entire message into it. Of course, using a HMAC is probably best. In principle you could then suffice with AES-CTR but I think it might still not be included in the MS runtimes.
